Как установить PyQt6?
Когда я пишу в терминал pip install pyqt6, то появляется ошибка:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
  × Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'PyQt6.sip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build` `Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt6-sip
Failed to build PyQt6-sip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (PyQt6-sip)

Python Interpreter: Python 3.8 (<name project>).
В других проектах установить PyQt6 получалось, но после того, как начал создавать проекты с git, то у меня появилась эта проблема.

Я пробовал по ссылке установить "Microsoft C++ Build Tools".

Пробовал через File -> Settings -> Project  -> Python
Interpreter, после чего нажал "+" и выбрал PyQt6, выводит ту же самую
ошибку.

Также пробовал обновить wheel, setuptools - не помогло, ошибка та же.



так вы попробовали установить по ссылке Build Tools - получилось у вас? и то ли вы установили, что надо?

Ну я перешел на сайт и нажал "Загрузить Build Tools", после этого у меня появился "Visual Studio Installer". Когда я в интернете искал решение проблемы, то там предлагали установить по ссылке Build Tools, и там в Visual Studio Installer был Build Tools 2019 для установки, но у меня почему-то в Visual Studio Installer в разделе "Доступно" находится 6 продуктов, из которых нету Build Tools. Если я что-то не так делаю в Visual Studio Installer или что-то неправильно понял, то можете пожалуйста подсказать? С такой проблемой встречаюсь в первый раз.

то, что вы скачали с сайта и есть Build Tools. судя по всему, вам нужно после запуска установщика выбрать "разработка классических приложений на C++" и установить.

А там разве 10,42 ГБ нужно устанавливать? Или где-то убрать галочки в "Сведения об установке"? Если что я в "Доступно" нажал кнопку "Установить" возле "Visual Studio Community 2022" и там выбрал "разработка классических приложений на C++"

«А там разве 10,42 ГБ нужно устанавливать?» — ну в общем-то да, если вы собираетесь компилировать PyQt6 из исходников. И ещё инструменты разработки Qt докинуть до кучи

А вообще попробуйте pip install --only-binary :all: pyqt6 чтобы подтянулась старая версия PyQt6-sip которая ещё была собрана под Python 3.8

Ну а фраза «получалось» объясняется тем, что из PyQt6-sip убрали сборку Python 3.8 как раз всего три дня назад

Спасибо всем за ответы, оказывается проблема и в правду была в версии Python, я ее поменял на 3.12, теперь 'pip install pyqt6' работает как надо.
